# Nodejs Converting Gulp to Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp

I use gulp default to start my nodejs server and watch for any changes. I want to instead do this simple example using webpack.

gulpfile. js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('default', function() {

    livereload.listen();

    nodemon({

        script: 'index.js',
        ext: 'js'

    }).on('restart', function() {

        gulp.src('index.js')
            .pipe(livereload())
            .pipe(notify('Reloading page, please wait...'));
    });

});
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.bunde.js'
    },
    target: 'node',
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "express-validator": "^4.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-install": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.0.0",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.13.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.9",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "twilio": "^4.6.0",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6"
  }
}
```

How can i convert this previous gulp setup to webpack.? I just simple want to be able to put a command to start my node server where the entry point in index.js and watch for any changes made in any of the .js files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `webpack` bin to build your app and watch for changes:

```
"scripts": {
  "start-server": "node server",
  "start-client": "webpack --config ./webpack.config --display-entrypoints --watch",
  "start": "start-server && start-client"
  ...
}
```